# Websocket-Rails Channel 'Error during WebSocket Handshake'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, websocket, puma

I'm trying to use websocket-rails to broadcast live routes as they come in to my site.  However, I'm unable to get any messages to be published.  I've read all of the help I could find, and I can't seem to get a solution.

Here is what the javascript I have in application.html.erb:

```
 var route_name = window.location.pathname + window.location.search;

 $.post("/realtimeroutes",
            { data: { route_name: route_name} },
            function(response) {

            }
    );
```

This data is handed off to a rails controller method realtime_routes which looks like this:

```
 def realtime_routes
     puts '*** The Route Data is: ' + params[:data][:route_name]);
     new_route = RouteCatcher.new(route_name: params[:data][:route_name]

     if new_route.save
        route = {route_name: params[:data][:route_name]}

        puts '*** Right before the Message is sent ***'

        WebsocketRails[:new_route].trigger('new', route)

        puts '*** Right After the Message is sent ***'
        render nothing: true
     else
        render nothing: true
     end
 end
```

To this point everything is fine.  updates are happening in the DB and both the before and after messages are printing to the console, but there is no Websocket Message fired.

Next I have this javascript listening in realtime.html.erb:

```
    var dispatcher = new WebSocketRails(window.location.host + '/websocket');

    var channel = dispatcher.subscribe('new_route');

    channel.bind('new', function(route) {
        console.log('********** Inside Bind Event');
        console.log('********** a new route '+ route.route_name +' arrived!');
    });
```

Nothing is ever being received on the bind event and when I look in the Console on Chrome, I get:

```
 'Uncaught ReferenceError: WebSocketRails is not defined'
```

So I'm absolutely stuck here as I've followed every bit of documentation I can find and really have no idea where to go.  Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:  That was an initialization error because the WebSocketRails was being rendered before the rest of the application js.

However, now I am getting the error:

```
 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 301
```

After reading further about other people with the same error, it seems prudent to mention that I am using Puma on AWS elasticbeanstalk with SSL in production.